# Selenium-Python selecting an element with empty Span

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

using xpath, I have a table that contains span on each cell, I am trying to select a button that has empty `<span>` at col2. How can you select it?

```
+-------+------+------+--------+
| col 1 | col2 | col3 | button |
+-------+------+------+--------+
| col   | f    | ch   | select |
| col   |      | ch   | select |
| col   | 2    | ch   | select |
| b     | n    | ch   | select |
+-------+------+------+--------+
```

i tried:

```
//span[text()="col"]/following::span/[text()='']following::span/[text()="ch"]/following::a[text()="select"][1]
```

and

```
//span[text()="col"]/following::span[normalize-space()]/following::span[text()="1"]/following::a[text()="select"][1]
```

but i don't know what to on the second `span/[text()='']` as that span contains nothing. just `<span></span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below XPath to select *link in table row that contains only 2 non-empty spans*:

```
//tr[count(.//span[text()])=2]//a[.="Select"]
```

If you need *link in table row which second span is empty*:

```
//tr[(.//span)[2][not(text())]]//a[.="Select"]
```

or even more suitable for your case:

```
//tr[(.//span)[1] = "col" and (.//span)[3] = "ch" and (.//span)[2][not(text())]]//a[.="Select"]
```

Comment: ohh.. but i need to determine check if column 1 and column 3 values are col and ch

Comment: Ok... Try `//tr[(.//span)[1] = "col" and (.//span)[3] = "ch" and (.//span)[2][not(text())]]//a[.="Select"]`

Comment: after a few iterations, it was not selecting anymore, odd.  Using each attribute individually works, but when i use two or more attribute using "and" it does not work anymore

Comment: @Led , I didn't see the actual HTML source, so it's hard to tell what exactly is wrong... Can you share HTML for the same table? Or post new ticket regarding this issue with HTML sample?

Comment: this is a sample table of what i am referring to https://jsfiddle.net/nozj3cu8/, im trying to select column 3

Comment: @Led , Do you still need to select `select` node in raw with empty 'column3` value, right?

Comment: yeah thats the goal, get the "select" with empty column 3. I tired your code but "and" is not working.

Comment: @Led , try this one `//tr[not(normalize-space(td[3]))]/td[normalize-space()="select"]`. You can extend first predicate if you want to take values of other cells into account: `[not(normalize-space(td[3])) and normalize-space(td[1])="Some text" and normalize-space(td[4])="Another text"]`

Comment: i think this works now, thank you very much with your patience, I appreciate it.